# Not able to run dump in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to dump a relation but getting following error.

I have tried `start-all.sh` and tried formatting namenode using `hadoop namenode -format`.

But I am not getting what is wrong.

```
Error:-
Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: Is that a Pig error, or a Hadoop error?

Comment: @cricket_007 : It looks it is a pig error

Comment: I see. Well, `pig -x local` doesn't touch any Hadoop configs, so I wouldn't test that. You are getting a retry error, so something cannot connect. I would guess it's in the `yarn-site.xml` and/or `core-site.xml` something is misconfigured considering `hdfs` commands can work

Comment: How to configure it?

Comment: Like I said, `$HADOOP_HOME/conf`. There is at least 3 XML files that you need to edit in order for Hadoop to be "properly configured" during installation. If you didn't do that, then read back over how to install Hadoop

Comment: See my bashrc file. 

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig
export PATH=$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"

Comment: I don't think all those need to be in bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the `JobHistoryServer`

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

Pig when ran in `mapreduce` mode expects the `JobHistoryServer` to be available.

To configure `JobHistoryServer`, add these properties to `mapred-site.xml` replacing hostname with actual name of the host where the process is started

```
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
   <value>hostname:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
   <value>hostname:19888</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Yes. If this pseudo distributed cluster, you can omit these properties and start `JobHistoryServer`

Answer (score 0):

I would first ensure I'm able to connect to namenode from hdfs client on a edge node. If not some problem/inconsistency with your namenode configs in core-site.xml file either with ports or hostname.

Once you are able to run below with out any issues and ensure namenode is not in safe mode on url http://namenode_host:50070 (which prevents any writes)

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

Then I would proceed with pig. Looks like based on your error hdfs client is unable to reach namenode for some reason which could be firewall or config issue.

Comment: hadop fs -ls / is running fine.
I have used this command to  turn off safe mode.
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
Again same error is coming.
2017-03-11 19:52:43,977 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server.
 Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Comment: Please note this problem is coming in HDFS mode.(I am trying to create UDF and run it).
Everything is working fine in pig -x local.